# How can a host in Westworld do this?

Tags: westworld-tv

As we have seen in the final episode of *Westworld* season one, hosts are attacking guests with firearms. But we know that all the firearms used in Westworld are provided by Delos Corp., and that firearms can't kill or injure humans. So how is it possible?

We have seen a similar thing in the [Season 2 trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSFZW5efo6M).

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't won't to spoil it, but here, he's asking for something different from the other question.

Comment: @Mithun Sarker Shuvro Just to clarify, are you asking just about Dolores or her and the other group? "that host .. a firearm" or "the hosts .. firearms"?

Comment: @madmada Dolores and her group .

Comment: Ok, I edited it the question a bit, and was already posted an answer.

Comment: The same exact thing happened in the movie.  When the robots started malfunctioning they suddenly were shooting the guests with the same guns that couldn't hurt people before.

Comment: A definitive answer comes from season 2 in the first 2 episodes, but I can't remember enough details to write a good answer. Someone please do it!

Answer (score 11):

Regarding Dolores part of the attack, it was a different gun than the ones used in the park. It's the "real" gun  Arnold gave to her decades ago to kill him with. In a scene just before the one in your question, Ford gave it back to her (put it in front of her and left it)

[image]

[image]

[image]

As for the others, it wasn't specifically mentioned, since it was the last scene and we knew they're using "real" guns from William's pov when he was shot, but it was heavily hinted that it was all Ford's plan from the beginning, so we can assume that he gave them the weapons too.